# A question about conditional expectation

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-expectation, compound-distributions

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ and $Y$ be random variables. I know that:

$$\label{aaa}\tag{I}
E\left[\sum_{j=1}^n  X_j \Bigg |  Y \right]=\sum_{j=1}^n E\left[ X_j \Big |  Y \right] $$

Now, suppose that $Y$ takes values $1,2, 3,...$.

How to prove the following?
$$E\left[\sum_{j=1}^Y  X_j \Bigg |  Y \right]=\sum_{j=1}^Y E\left[ X_j \Big |  Y \right] $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\sum_{j = 1}^Y E[X_j|Y]$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable, to show it is the conditional expectation as desired, it is sufficient to show for any $n \in \{1, 2, \ldots\}$, it holds that (this is because any $\sigma(Y)$-set can be written as the union of sets of the form $\{Y = n\}$).
\begin{align}
\int_{\{Y = n\}}\sum_{j = 1}^Y X_j dP = \int_{\{Y = n\}}\sum_{j = 1}^Y E[X_j|Y]dP. 
\end{align}

Indeed,
\begin{align}
LHS &= \int_\Omega \sum_{j = 1}^Y X_j I_{\{Y = n\}}dP
= \int_\Omega \sum_{j = 1}^n X_j I_{\{Y = n\}}dP  \\
    &= \sum_{j = 1}^n\int_{\{Y = n\}}X_jdP \\
    &= \sum_{j = 1}^n\int_{\{Y = n\}}E[X_j | Y]dP \\
    &= \int_{\{Y = n\}}\sum_{j = 1}^n E[X_j|Y]dP  = 
    \int_{\{Y = n\}}\sum_{j = 1}^Y E[X_j|Y]dP = RHS. 
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. I only need understand the following $$\sum_{j = 1}^n\int_{\{Y = n\}}X_jdP  = \sum_{j = 1}^n\int_{\{Y = n\}}E[X_j | Y]dP$$.

Comment: I got it, thank you!